# gstreamer pipeline doesn't play when using `omxh264dec`

Tags: pi-3, video, gpu, gstreamer, h264

I would like to decode H.264 video with gstreamer, taking advantage of hardware acceleration on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model A+.

My pipelines work when using `avdec_h264`, but when I substitute this for the OpenMAX H.264 Video Decoder, `omxh264dec`, the pipeline never plays and no window appears.

- I am using “Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy)”, 32-bit, `2023-12-05-raspios-bullseye-armhf`, Kernel 6.1.21, GStreamer 1.18.4
- `gst-inspect-1.0 omxh264dec` confirms that the element is present.
- The behaviour is the same:

  - with more or less GPU memory enabled
  - with `vc4-kms-v3d` or `vc4-fkms-v3d`
  - With Glamor enabled or disabled
  - Using different sinks such as `ximagesink` or `glimagesink`

Below are simple test pipelines to demonstrate the behaviour.

The following pipeline works, encoding with `x264enc` and decoding with `avdec_h264`:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
  videotestsrc pattern=smpte ! \
  video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,framerate=5/1 ! \
  x264enc ! \
  h264parse ! \
  avdec_h264 ! \
  videoconvert ! \
  videorate ! \
  autovideosink
```

The following pipelines work, encoding with `omxh264enc` and decoding with `omxh264dec` via an intermediate file:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
  videotestsrc num-buffers=25 pattern=smpte ! \
  video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,framerate=5/1 ! \
  videoconvert ! \
  omxh264enc ! \
  filesink location=o.h264

gst-launch-1.0 -v \
  filesrc location=o.h264 ! \
  h264parse ! \
  omxh264dec ! \
  videoconvert ! \
  videorate ! \
  video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,framerate=5/1 ! \
  autovideosink
```

However, the following pipeline, encoding with `omxh264enc` and directly decoding with `omxh264dec` hangs and never plays:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
  videotestsrc pattern=smpte ! \
  video/x-raw,width=320,height=240,framerate=5/1 ! \
  omxh264enc ! \
  h264parse ! \
  omxh264dec ! \
  videoconvert ! \
  videorate ! \
  autovideosink
```

Is there something missing from my OpenMAX pipeline or my system configuration? Is there something else I could try to debug the issue?